# How can we make sure that data being fetched in one dataFetcher being available in other dataFetcher in a grapghQL java project

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, typegraphql

I am very new to GraphQL. Below is my init method in my Resolver

```
    public void init() {
        builder.type("SystemTopic", typeWiring -> typeWiring
                .dataFetcher("items", this::itemsConnection).dataFetcher("payloads", this::getPayloads));
    }
```

I need the data fetched in **items** in fetcher in payloads fetcher. The seconds fetcher **payloads** execution starts before **items** done its job. So, some required data is missing in payloads.

I tried by adding dataLatch waiting time in the **payloads** fetcher it seems working some times but not always. I look for permanent and feasible solution.

I expect that whatever the data being added  to the Context in the first fetcher, it should be available in the **payloads**.

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Thank you, Syamala.